# How to share the same In-Memory DB from 2 different .NET Core Apps?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

Example:

- App 1, queries data from an In-Memory database called "ABC"
- App 2, inserts data to the same In-Memory "ABC" database

Can they REALLY share the data if the In-Memory database has the same name?

Comment: You can create a class library project, install in memory package and add definition for DbContext and entities; then you can reference your class library project from apps projects. Use the same name for in memory database

Comment: OK, so I suppose that it's not possible to share an In-Memory DB from 2 different processes, right?

Comment: @superJMN No In-memory cannot be accessed from 2 different process.